# Installing zimbra on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, zimbra

Error: no such file ":Aborting, unknown platform: UBUNTUUNKNOWN_64"

i was trying to install zimbra on ubuntu 20.04. Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: I looked around Zimbra pages and it seems they don't support anything past Ubuntu Linux 14.04.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Zimbra is definitely supported on Ubuntu 20.04: see https://www.zimbra.com/downloads/zimbra-collaboration/

Comment: Could you elaborate on your system setup? CPU architecture, installed ubuntu version (server/desktop), installed zimbra version, ...

Comment: which zimbra version ? OSE ? NE ? 8.8.15 ? 9.0 ? which builder Zextras ? SYNACCOR ?